# How Do I Center Product Title And Pricing Info On My Shopify Website?

Tags: css, shopify, product, center, title

I'm trying to figure out how to center the title of the product I'm selling on my website (Safe Guard Lenz) as well as center the pricing details that's under the product title as well. I need them centered for both mobile and desktop.

It's located at the bottom of the home page and on the product page itself. Ideally would want it centered for both.

Any help to achieve this would be greatly appreciated as I've been looking for a solution for this online and can't seem to have any success.

My website is safeguardlenz.com and the password is: Bebe

Thank you!

Comment: Would you like to show me a screenshot, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use style sth like this.

```
.product-single__title{
  text-align: center;
}

.product__price, #automizely_reviews_product_detail_title_star_widget{
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
}
```

[image]

#### And this is the style for homepage value.

```
.price__pricing-group {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Exactly! This worked, although on the home page the price wasn't centered, is there a way to fix that part? I really appreciate your help Oscar!

Comment: Good to hear about it works. I've updated my answer. Please have a check on the style that I added to the end.

Comment: That fixed my issue, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Would you like to upvote my answer if it works for you? :D

Comment: I'm a new user so I can't upvote it until I get 15 myself, I emailed your portfolio page because I'm sure I'll need more help and I don't like the idea of someone doing something for me for free all the time, is there a way I can easily contact you?

Comment: You can email here `oscar@cardoso-devstar.com`. This is my email. And this is my GitHub: `https://github.com/cardoso-topdev`. You can follow my Github. Thanks. :D